# How can I post a bunch of checkbox names to an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm looking to get a bunch of checkboxes (all with the same class) and get all the attribute names and push all the checked boxes into an array (also remove them from the array if they get unchecked).

Eventually, I want to pass an array of what was checked via ajax, and the ajax refreshes every time a box is checked/unchecked.

Any ideas on how I'd do this?

Comment: @zerkms its a how can.. if he'd tried it,guessing he would've posted -- problem with.. ;)

Comment: Vivek: some people try and some people want you to write their code for them without even trying. I like people who try, even if they get stuck.

Comment: @Vivek Chandra: selecting objects by class is the very basic thing. If you cannot do it - you literally know nothing about jQuery

Comment: @zerkms diodeus i know.. i was being sarcastic towards adamzwakk.. :) .. i've seen a lot of how to's.. and,it usually comes directly -- not after trying.. it was a rhetorical question..

Comment: I'm not looking for someone to write it for me, just a bump in the right direction. Just to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$.map` to get all the names of checkboxes in an array.

```
var names = $('.theClassName').map(function() {
     return this.name;
});
```

For second part of your question.

To get only `checked` checkboxes use `$('.theClassName:checked')`. You don't have to maintain an array for this.

Comment: I've never used the map function yet, but I'm not sure it will do everything I need. I'll update my question with a bit more details.

Comment: @adamzwakk: why don't you read the documentation to become absolutely sure if it is or it is not what you was looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
var names = [];
$('.theClassName').each(function() {
  var name = $(this).attr('name');
  names.push(name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = $('input.class_name:checked').map(function {
    return $(this).attr('name');
})
```

will fill an array with the names of the checked checkboxes.

Comment: Any **real** reason in such selector: `class^="class_name"` ?

Comment: he said he wanted all the check boxes with the same class name

Comment: yes, and `same name` != `starts with the same substring`, is it? Your rule will also match checkboxes with class `class_name2`, which is just unexpected. The same name criteria for your case could be `input.class_name:checked`